# How to show $\rho(\beta_0, \beta_1) \leq 0$?

Tags: regression, correlation, covariance

Consider a simple linear regression $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \epsilon_i$ where each $\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$.
The solution to the linear regression problem is given by $\pmb{\beta} = (\pmb{X}^{T}\pmb{X})^{-1}\pmb{X}^{T}\pmb{Y}$ and the variance-covariance matrix is $\text{Var}(\pmb{\beta}) = \sigma^2 (\pmb{X}^{T}\pmb{X})^{-1}$.

Provided $x_i \geq 0$ for each index $i$, I want to show that $\rho(\hat{\beta_0}, \hat{\beta_1}) \leq 0,$ where $\rho(\cdot, \cdot)$ denotes the correlation.

---

I tried expanded the correlation definition, and I think enough to show covariance is negative. However, I'm having trouble doing so. I've used the definition of correlation, and I think I need to make use of the fact that $x_i \geq 0$, but I'm not able to get anywhere.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Could you show us how far you got?  What expression did you develop for $(X^\prime X)^{-1},$ for instance? All you need to do is inspect the sign of its off-diagonal entry (and for that purpose you don't even need to find the inverse--computing the adjugate of $X^\prime X$ will suffice, because the determinant of $X^\prime X$ clearly is positive).

Answer (score 3):

I will set forth the argument doing as little algebra as possible, working from basic definitions.

$\mathbf X$ is the *model matrix:* its rows are numerical representations of the observations and its columns are the regressor variables recorded for each observation. (The vector $y$ separately records the values of the response variable.) Usually $X$ also includes a constant column used to model the constant, or "intercept," term.

In Ordinary Least Squares regression there is just one regressor variable, often denoted $\mathbf x = (x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n).$  Thus, placing the constant column first in the model matrix,

$$\mathbf{X} = \pmatrix{1&x_1 \\ 1&x_2 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & x_n}\text{ and }\mathbf y = \pmatrix{y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_n}.$$

We can proceed only by supposing the $x_i$ aren't all the same number (which is implicit in the question).  According to your formula $\sigma^2 \left(\mathbf X^\prime \mathbf X\right)^{-1},$ the variance of the coefficient estimates $\hat\beta=(\hat\beta_0,\hat\beta_1)$ is a positive multiple ($\sigma^2$) of the matrix inverse of

$$\mathbf  X^\prime \mathbf X = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 \\ x_1 & x_2 & \ldots & x_n}\pmatrix{1&x_1 \\ 1&x_2 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & x_n} = \pmatrix{n & \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \\ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i & \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2},$$

as you can compute using the rule of matrix multiplication.  (If you track through the remainder of this analysis closely, you can confirm that **only one of these calculations is actually needed:** the upper right corner of this matrix product is $(1,1,\ldots,1)(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)^\prime = \sum x_i.$)

The inverse of $\mathbf  X^\prime \mathbf X$ is its *adjugate* divided by its determinant, where

$$\operatorname{ad} \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} = \pmatrix{d&-b\\-c&a}$$

and

$$\det \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} = ad-bc.$$

You can readily confirm this by multiplication:

$$\left[\frac{1}{\det \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}} \operatorname{ad} \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\right]\, \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} = \frac{1}{ad-bc}\pmatrix{ad-bc & 0 \\ 0 & ad-bc}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}.$$

We need to be concerned about the sign of the determinant.  Since for any 2-vector $\mathbf v$ it is the case that

$$\mathbf v^\prime \left(\mathbf X^\prime \mathbf X\right)\mathbf v = \mathbf w^\prime \mathbf w = ||\mathbf w ||^2 \ge 0,$$

where $\mathbf w = \mathbf {X v},$ it follows from this (and from the non-constancy of $\mathbf x$) that $\mathbf X^\prime \mathbf X$ is positive definite, whence its determinant cannot be negative.  **This is a nice argument because it requires no calculation at all.**

(Alternatively, if you are a glutton for doing algebra, you may compute

$$\det \mathbf X^\prime \mathbf X = n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2 = n^2 \operatorname{Var}(\mathbf x) \gt 0$$

which shows the same thing.)

**The off-diagonal terms of the inverse of $\mathbf X^\prime \mathbf X$ therefore are positive multiples of $-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i.$**  When you assume all the $x_i$ are non-negative (and at least one is positive), this expression clearly is negative.  Consequently, according to the formula you cite, the covariance (and hence the correlation) of $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$ must be negative, *QED.*

In reviewing the argument, **please notice that only one extremely easy calculation was involved: we had to sum the $x_i$ when computing $\mathbf X^\prime \mathbf X.$**

Geometrically, when you wiggle a line through the scatterplot of points $(x_i,y_i)$ in an effort to approximate those points, tilting the line up increases the slope $\hat\beta_1$ with a consequent *decrease* in the intercept $\hat\beta_0,$ which (since the $x_i$ are nonnegative) lies to the left of all the points in the scatterplot.  That's what it means to be negatively correlated.

[image: Figure]

Comment: Because if the determinant were negative, the factor $1/\det(X^\prime X)$ that multiplies the adjugate would change the signs of all its components!

Comment: How'd you get that the determinant equals $n^2 \sigma^2_x$? I can't get the last equality

Comment: It's straightforward algebra. (In fact, in many references this is the *definition* of the variance.)  Try it by writing out the sums when $n=2.$ Note that the variance of a set of numbers is *not* an estimator: the divisions are all by $n,$ with no factors of $n-1$ involved.

Comment: I still don't see it. For $n = 2$, I get $n(x_1^2 + x_2^2) - (x_1 + x_2)^2 = (n - 1)(x_1^2 + x_2^2) - 2x_1x_2$. The variance is $\sum_{i} x_i^2 - \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_i x_i)\right)^2$

Comment: The variance is $(1/n)\sum x_i^2 - \left(1/n \sum x_i\right)^2.$

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that $x=(1,2,3)$. Then the $X$ matrix is
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$
and $X^TX$ is
\begin{align*}
X^TX&=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 6 \\ 6 & 14 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix} n & \sum_ix_i \\ \sum_ix_i & \sum_ix_i^2 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Finally, $(X^TX)^{-1}$ is
\begin{align*}
(X^TX)^{-1}&=\frac16\begin{bmatrix} 14 & -6 \\ -6 & 3 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \frac{1}{n\sum_ix_i^2-(\sum_ix_i)^2}\begin{bmatrix}\sum_ix_i^2 & -\sum_ix_i \\ -\sum_ix_i & n \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
In general (see Seber & Lee, *Linear Regression Analysis*, John Wiley & Sons, 2003, Example 4.6), putting $X=[1_n,X_1]$:
$$X^TX=\begin{bmatrix}n & n\bar{x}^T \\ n\bar{x} & X_1^TX_1 \end{bmatrix},
\quad
(X^TX)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac1n+\bar{x}^TV^{-1}\bar{x} & -\bar{x}^TV^{-1} \\ -V^{-1}\bar{x} & V^{-1} \end{bmatrix} $$
where $V=\tilde{X}^T\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{X}$ has tipical element $\tilde{x}_{ij}=x_{ij}-\bar{x}_j$.

Is this enough?